# Connecting jira to redash

Tags: database, jira, jql, redash, tempo

Has anyone an experience in connecting jira into redash? I've found the instruction on redash website, and finely connected to my jira account, but i want to do something like tempo report (in jira) in redash, with user filters to make reports for different customers, cause they have different report forms.
All i have now is only writing a JQL query in redash and i get the same table like in jira, its not that i wanted to do). Maybe someone have a manual how to save a JQL query as a database, and then it will be more simple to make user filters in redash. Maybe you have another ideas about this story?

Comment: I solved it with jira api on python

Comment: Glad you solved it. I added an answer in case someone else comes looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [query filters](https://redash.io/help/user-guide/querying/query-filters) to filter data in a [Query Results Data Source](https://redash.io/help/user-guide/querying/query-results-data-source) query that pulls the results of the Jira data source query.

For example here's a Jira data source query pulling in some issues that match a few criteria:

```
{
  "fields": "key,statuscategorychangedate,resolutiondate,resolution,customfield_12593,customfield_12518,customfield_10004",
  "jql": "(sprint = 'Sprint 83') and sprint is not empty and project = LRN ",
  "fieldMapping": {
      "customfield_12593": "dev_points",
      "customfield_12518": "qa_points",
      "customfield_10004": "total_points"
  }
}
```

If the ID for that query (in the URL) is `123` then I can create a Query Results data source query in SQLite like this:

```
select resolution_name as "resolution::multiFilter", * from query_123
```

Note the ID is used in `from query_123`.

And `"resolution::multiFilter"` allows the results to be filtered based on all the values that are returned for `resolution`.

This should be easily applied to the Jira data you want to query and the user values you want to filter.